# Camera2 API and java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I'm creating an app which supports deprecated and new camera API. The first one works like a charm but i'm struggling with Camera2 API. In a phase of testing I've noticed strange behaviour. Testing device is Samsung Galaxy S5 with android 6.0.1
When i press the Power/End key and then go back to application this is what I get(it does not happen everytime):

```
03-12 16:14:32.704 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onPause
03-12 16:14:32.774 24117-24128/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24117-2] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 16:14:32.784 24117-24145/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24117-2] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 16:14:33.044 24117-24128/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24117-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 16:14:33.044 24117-24145/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24117-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 16:14:33.054 24117-24129/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24117-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 16:14:33.054 24117-24128/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24117-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 16:14:33.264 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: cameraComponentsReleased
03-12 16:14:33.264 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: StopCameraThread
03-12 16:14:33.264 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraApiManager: cameraPreviewRemoved
03-12 16:14:33.264 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceDestroyed
03-12 16:14:33.634 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onCreate
03-12 16:14:33.634 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onResume
03-12 16:14:33.634 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: startCameraThread
03-12 16:14:33.634 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraApiManager: cameraPreviewCreated
03-12 16:14:33.644 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: initCamera
03-12 16:14:33.674 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceCreated
03-12 16:14:33.674 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: openCamera
03-12 16:14:33.914 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceChanged
03-12 16:14:33.914 24117-25053/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onOpened
03-12 16:14:33.914 24117-25053/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: createCameraPreview
03-12 16:14:33.934 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onPause
03-12 16:14:34.174 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: cameraComponentsReleased
03-12 16:14:34.174 24117-25053/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onConfigured
03-12 16:14:34.174 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: StopCameraThread
03-12 16:14:34.174 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraApiManager: cameraPreviewRemoved
03-12 16:14:34.184 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceDestroyed
03-12 16:14:34.914 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onResume
03-12 16:14:34.914 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: startCameraThread
03-12 16:14:34.924 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraApiManager: cameraPreviewCreated
03-12 16:14:34.924 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: initCamera
03-12 16:14:34.964 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceCreated
03-12 16:14:34.964 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: openCamera
03-12 16:14:35.294 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceChanged
03-12 16:14:35.294 24117-25121/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onOpened
03-12 16:14:35.294 24117-25121/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: createCameraPreview
03-12 16:14:35.354 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceChanged
03-12 16:14:35.374 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onPause
03-12 16:14:35.384 24117-25121/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onConfigured
03-12 16:14:35.594 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: cameraComponentsReleased
03-12 16:14:35.594 24117-25121/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: Session was closed or camera device has been closed. 
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1997)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:844)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:899)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:236)
                                                                      at pl.tripper.tripper.camera.CameraNewApi$2.onConfigured(CameraNewApi.java:107)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-12 16:14:35.594 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: StopCameraThread
03-12 16:14:35.594 24117-25121/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: cameraComponentsReleased
03-12 16:14:35.594 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraApiManager: cameraPreviewRemoved
03-12 16:14:35.604 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceDestroyed
03-12 16:14:35.644 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onCreate
03-12 16:14:35.654 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onResume
03-12 16:14:35.654 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: startCameraThread
03-12 16:14:35.654 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraApiManager: cameraPreviewCreated
03-12 16:14:35.654 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: initCamera
03-12 16:14:35.694 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceCreated
03-12 16:14:35.694 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: openCamera
03-12 16:14:35.934 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onSurfaceChanged
03-12 16:14:35.934 24117-25184/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onOpened
03-12 16:14:35.934 24117-25184/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: createCameraPreview
03-12 16:14:35.944 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-12 16:14:35.944 24117-24117/pl.tripper.tripper E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-12 16:14:35.994 24117-25184/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onConfigured
```

Added some error logs when methods are called. I know that cameraDevice is null when session is still up, but i have no idea how to fix it. Camera keeps working after `java.lang.IllegalStateException` error ocurrs. The second problem is `BufferQueueProducer` error but i cannot figure out where this is come from.

```
03-12 15:47:40.244 30720-30731/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-30720-1] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 15:47:40.244 30720-30751/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-30720-1] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 15:47:40.524 30720-30731/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-30720-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 15:47:40.524 30720-30751/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-30720-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 15:47:40.524 30720-30732/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-30720-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-12 15:47:40.524 30720-30731/pl.tripper.tripper E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-30720-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

Here is my code:

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        isImmersiveAvailable();
        cameraApiManager = new CameraApiManager(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
       cameraApiManager.createCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        cameraApiManager.releaseCameraAndPreview();
    }
```

CameraApiManager.class

```
public class CameraApiManager implements CameraUtility.cameraOpenedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraApiManager";

    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivity;
    private Context context;

    private CameraSourceApi cameraSourceApi;
    private CameraPreview cameraPreview;

    public CameraApiManager(Context context, MainActivity mainActivity){

        this.mainActivity= new WeakReference<>(mainActivity);

        cameraSourceApi = new CameraSourceApi<>(new CameraNewApi(context));
        this.context = context;
    }

    private boolean cameraProgressBarEnable(){
        return context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.camera_progress_bar_enable);
    }

    private void setCameraProgressBarVisibility(final int visibility ){
        final MainActivity mainActivity = this.mainActivity.get();
        if(mainActivity!= null){
            // UI/Main Thread
            if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()){
                ProgressBar cameraProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.camera_progress_bar);
                cameraProgressBar.setVisibility(visibility);
            } else {
                mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ProgressBar cameraProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.camera_progress_bar);
                        cameraProgressBar.setVisibility(visibility);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void showCameraOpenErrorToast(){
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.camera_open_error_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private boolean cameraPermissionGranted() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public void createCamera(){
        if(cameraPermissionGranted()){
            if(cameraProgressBarEnable()){
                setCameraProgressBarVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            cameraSourceApi.createCamera(this);
        }
    }

    public void releaseCameraAndPreview(){
        if(cameraPermissionGranted()){
            cameraSourceApi.releaseCamera();
            removeCameraPreview();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraOpened(boolean succeeded, boolean addPreview, boolean progressBar) {
         if(addPreview) {
             if (cameraPreview == null) {
                 Log.e(TAG, "cameraPreviewCreated");
                 cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(context, cameraSourceApi);
                 addCameraPreview();
             }
         }
         if(!progressBar){
             if(cameraProgressBarEnable()){
                 setCameraProgressBarVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
         }
         if(!succeeded){
             showCameraOpenErrorToast();
         }
    }

    private void addCameraPreview(){
        MainActivity mainActivity = this.mainActivity.get();
        if(mainActivity != null && cameraPreview != null){
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(cameraPreview);
        }
    }

    private void removeCameraPreview(){
        MainActivity mainActivity = this.mainActivity.get();
        if(mainActivity!= null && cameraPreview != null){
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraPreviewRemoved");
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.removeView(cameraPreview);
            cameraPreview = null;
        }
    }

     class CameraSourceApi<T extends CameraUtility> implements CameraUtility{

        private T camera;

        CameraSourceApi(T camera){
            this.camera = camera;
        }

        @Override
        public void createCamera(CameraUtility.cameraOpenedListener cameraOpenedListener) {
            camera.createCamera(cameraOpenedListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void releaseCamera() {
            camera.releaseCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            camera.onSurfaceCreated(surfaceHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int width, int height) {
            camera.onSurfaceChanged(surfaceHolder, width, height);
        }

         @Override
         public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
             camera.onSurfaceDestroyed(surfaceHolder);
         }
     }
}
```

CameraNewApi.class

```
@TargetApi(21)
class CameraNewApi implements CameraUtility {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraNewApi";

    private Semaphore cameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

    private CameraUtility.cameraOpenedListener cameraOpenedListener;

    private Context context;

    private Handler backgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread backgroundThread;

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    private String backFacingCameraId;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;

    CameraNewApi(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice = camera;
            if(surfaceHolder != null){
                createCameraPreview();
            } else {
                releaseCameraComponents();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "deviceCallback.onDisconnected() start");
            Log.e(TAG, "onDisconnected");
            if(cameraOpenedListener != null) {
                cameraOpenedListener.onCameraOpened(false, false, false);
            }
            cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            camera.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError");
            Log.d(TAG, "deviceCallback.onError() start");
            if(cameraOpenedListener != null) {
                cameraOpenedListener.onCameraOpened(false, false, false);
            }
            cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            camera.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private final CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback captureSessionStateCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onConfigured");
            if(cameraDevice != null){
                cameraCaptureSessions = session;
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
                try {
                    if(cameraOpenedListener != null) {
                        cameraOpenedListener.onCameraOpened(true, false, false);
                    }
                    session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera has been disconnected", e);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Session was closed or camera device has been closed. ", e);
                    releaseCameraComponents();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Capture session configure failed: " + session);
            Log.e(TAG, "onConfigureFailed");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void createCamera(CameraUtility.cameraOpenedListener cameraOpenedListener) {
        this.cameraOpenedListener = cameraOpenedListener;

        startBackgroundThread();
        if(cameraOpenedListener != null){
            cameraOpenedListener.onCameraOpened(true, true, true);
        }
        initCamera();
    }

    private void releaseCameraComponents(){
        try{
            cameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            if(cameraCaptureSessions != null){
                cameraCaptureSessions.close();
                cameraCaptureSessions = null;
            }
            if(cameraDevice != null){
                cameraDevice.close();
                cameraDevice = null;
            }
            if(surfaceHolder != null){
                surfaceHolder = null;
            }
            if(cameraOpenedListener != null){
                cameraOpenedListener = null;
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraComponentsReleased");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
        } finally {
            cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void releaseCamera() {
        releaseCameraComponents();
        stopBackgroundThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated");
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int width, int height) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged");
        setSurfaceSize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceDestroyed");
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        Log.e(TAG, "startCameraThread");
        backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        backgroundThread.start();
        backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        Log.e(TAG, "StopCameraThread");
        backgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            backgroundThread.join();
            backgroundThread = null;
            backgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error message: ", e);
        }
    }

    private void initCamera(){
        Log.e(TAG, "initCamera");
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try{
            for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                        = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // Use back camera
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
                    backFacingCameraId = cameraId;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(backFacingCameraId == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not detect a camera");
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get camera list", e);
        }
    }

    private void openCamera(){
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera");
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            if(backFacingCameraId != null && cameraDevice == null){
                try{
                    if (!cameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
                    }
                    cameraManager.openCamera(backFacingCameraId, cameraDeviceStateCallback, backgroundHandler);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
                }
            }
        } catch(SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera permission is not granted", e);
        } catch(CameraAccessException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not open camera", e);
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreview(){

        Log.e(TAG, "createCameraPreview");
        Surface surface = surfaceHolder.getSurface();

        List<Surface> surfaceList = Collections.singletonList(surface);

        try {
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaceList, captureSessionStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create capture session for camera: " + cameraDevice.getId(), e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera has been closed", e);
        }
    }
```

CameraUtility.interface

```
interface CameraUtility {

    void createCamera(CameraUtility.cameraOpenedListener cameraOpenedListener);
    void releaseCamera();
    void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder);
    void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int width, int height);
    void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder);

    interface cameraOpenedListener{
        void onCameraOpened(boolean succeeded, boolean addPreview, boolean progressBar);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

That's why it does not happen everytime. Error occurs when right after onPause is called, session starts to repeat requests to maintain preview(onConfigured). Then cameraComponentsReleased triggers where all the cleanup is done, including current CameraDevice object. Still don't have a clue how to manage this situation.

```
03-13 12:12:24.375 17555-17555/pl.tripper.tripper E/MainActivity: onPause
03-13 12:12:24.395 17555-20454/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: onConfigured
03-13 12:12:24.625 17555-17555/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: cameraComponentsReleased
03-13 12:12:24.625 17555-17555/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: StopCameraThread
03-13 12:12:24.625 17555-20454/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: Session was closed or camera device has been closed. 
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1997)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:844)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:899)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:236)
                                                                      at pl.tripper.tripper.camera.CameraNewApi$2.onConfigured(CameraNewApi.java:114)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
                                                                      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-13 12:12:24.625 17555-20454/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraNewApi: Camera onClosed
03-13 12:12:24.625 17555-17555/pl.tripper.tripper E/CameraApiManager: cameraPreviewRemoved
```

Answer (score 5):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
```

This means CameraDevice is closed by someone in certain situation. (ex:Out of memory) To handle this, you can add onClosed() callback in your StateCallback - cameraDeviceStateCallback.

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback.onClosed(CameraDevice)
```

**Updated:**

It looks like a race condition. In the log, `17555-17555 releaseCameraComponents` and `17555-20454 onConfigured` callback is called on the different threads. IMO, cameraCaptureSessions should be synchronized in `releaseCameraComponents` and `onConfigured`.

```
private void releaseCameraComponents(){
     synchronized(lock) {
          ....
     }
}
....

@Override
public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: @You Kim - I think you are right. There are a few possible race conditions with the camera2Basic example, but the onConfigured callback is effectively the last step in the open sequence so it makes sense to have this included in any synchronisation plans.

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html if you didn't know how to use it like myself.

Comment: I'm prefer handler thread  or single scheduler in order to handle h/w resource like camera, audio, telephony, ble, etc. especially when resource has a status.    Also I prefer avoiding calling resource API inside resource callback.

Answer (score 4):

```
mCameraOpenCloseLock.release()
```

this Semaphore should be released after the camera createCaptureSession action to prevent resource conflicts between multiple threads. The source code releases the semaphore too early just after camera opened. Pausing the app will close the camera which causes the error.

To test it, call `finish()` before `mCameraOpenCloseLock.release()`, you will not see the error

Comment: can you explain more on how to use this?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it helped me immensely.

Answer (score -1):

1> First of All,Please create a Semaphore 'mCameraOpenCloseLock' to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.
Use google's recommended example :-
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

2> This Semaphore is released in onOpened() of CameraDevice.StateCallback which is not correct,so please remove it. It should be released at the end of onConfigured() in  createCameraPreviewSession(). That means the semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock is released after the camera preview session is completed successfully.